# Why is the fish binding not working in mac os?

Tags: fish

I am trying to use some of the fish bindings and I can't make them work in my Apple sierra with both iterm2 and terminal.

For example, when I use `Alt + d` which is supposed to kill a word, it inserts the letter `∂`

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to configure the terminal to treat the option/alt key as a "meta" key that prefaces the next key with an escape rather than a compose key. This doesn't really have anything to do with fish. If you used bindings in bash or zsh that expected [Alt-some_key] to work you'd see the same problem.

In iTerm2 open the preferences, go to "Profiles", then click the "Keys" tab. Near the bottom you'll see options to configure the left and right option/alt key to either act normally, as a meta key, or a Esc+ prefix. You want the latter option.

In Terminal open the preferences, select "Profiles", then click the "Keyboard" tab. At the bottom of the pane select the "Use Option as Meta Key".