# How do I use Fish's Alt bindings using Kitty on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-events, fish

I acquired a macOS machine for the first time, and I can't figure out how to use commands such as <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to [open the current command in `$EDITOR`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/interactive.html#command-line-editor).

I don't want to remap the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key to <kbd>alt</kbd> system-wide, but I can't figure out how to the remap in either Kitty or Fish.

[Why is the fish binding not working in mac os?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000512/why-is-the-fish-binding-not-working-in-mac-os) is a relevant question but the answer there only applies to iTerm2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kitty allows treating <kbd>⌥</kbd> as alt with [macos_option_as_alt](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/conf/#opt-kitty.macos_option_as_alt). So I've put

```
macos_option_as_alt yes
```

into `kitty.conf` and started using <kbd>⌥</kbd> as my <kbd>alt</kbd> replacement on macOS.

It seems that it's discouraged on macOS to reuse <kbd>⌘</kbd> as a modifier.

Answer (score 1):

By pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, I found out that the shell gets "[101;9u", so I've decided to create a custom binding:

```
bind "[101;9u" edit_command_buffer
```

This way I get the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> equivalent on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

Just share my experience:
You can use
[image]
then you can use `<ESC>e` to map in nvim